# iPhone drop down list

Tags: iphone

I didn't find the drop down list in the iPhone library. Instead of drop down list, is there any other alternative. Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can add UIPickerView or you can use UITableView instead. Apple has not provided any specific drop down menu.

**follow these steps:**

1) Include this delegate in your .h file:

```
        <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

2) Draw table, (initially it will be hidden) create "objTableView" in .h file.

```
        objTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,320,320) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            objTableView.delegate = self;
            objTableView.dataSource = self;
            objTableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
            objTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            objTableView.alpha = 0.7;
            objTableView.rowHeight=55.0;
            objTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            objTableView.hidden = YES;     //HIDDEN
            [self.view addSubview:objTableView];
```

3) Call this function where u want to display the table, it will show the table.

```
        -(void)menuButtonClicked:(id) sender
        {
            objTableView.hidden = NO;     //set HIDDEN NO
        }
```

4) You must have to override these funcions in your .m file

```
        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {

        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
        *)indexPath
        {

        }

        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

        }
```

5) If u again hide the table anywhere simply write

```
    objTableView.hidden = YES;
```

6) If I am not clear feel free to tell me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

u can use UIPickerView for this.  first create UITextfield and UIButton with arrow type image  and set button next to text field .

create pickerView and set thier frame to (0,481,width,height) in case of iphone. and add one toolbar with tow button @"done"  @"cancel" .and set it above to pickerView

on clicking on button show picker with animation like keyboard.

on clicking on cancel button hide picker with animation like Keyboard

and last on clicking done button set the text field value with selected pickerview row value 
and hide the picker view

hopu u got it :)

Answer (score 0):

UIPicker. Apple recommends using it instead of drop-down lists and comboboxes, that are less usable on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a tutorial on how to do this using a UIPickerView and UIActionSheet.. I was stuck with this for a while and had to combine bits of code I found in different places so hopefully it will help to have them all in one place :)

[Drop down lists for iPhone: rolling your own](http://t2a.co/blog/index.php/drop-down-lists-for-iphone-rolling-your-own/)

Answer (score 0):

here is another way of doing it
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/

Or here is one not everyone knows:  The action sheet is basically a drop down list if you think about it.  And if you keep adding buttons to a UIActionSheet it ends up turning into a table.  So just have your button call a UIActionSheet.

[image]